# View All Products only shows 3 products

Tags: toolbar, pager

I´m having the issue that if I click "View all" products in my toolbar then what I get back is a category page with the limit of 3 products instead of all.

I have checked and I think I know where the issue is but I can´t resolve it.
If i set the pager to all (in total 500 products)

```
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->getSize(); // returns 500
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count(); //returns 3
```

If I set the pager to 200

```
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->getSize(); // returns 200
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count(); //returns 200
```

What could be the issue?

**Update**

I have

```
$_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
echo $_productCollection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

And for every numerical limit set in the frontend of the category page I get an SQL query back

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position'.......
ORDER BY `publishingdate` desc LIMIT 6
```

Limit changes all the time depending on the Limit I set in the Pager Toolbar
but if I click on 'All' then I get this

```
ORDER BY `publishingdate` desc LIMIT 3
```

**Update**
I have not changed the function or anything for the limit, I just add the limits in the backend. So the function to set the limit etc. would be as usual

```
<div class="pager">
    <p class="amount">
        <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('Books %s-%s of %s', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('%s Book(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>

    <div class="limiter">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                <?php echo $_limit ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>

    </div>

    <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>

</div>
```

And then the function

```
  protected function _getAvailableLimit($mode)
        {
            if (isset($this->_availableLimit[$mode])) {
                return $this->_availableLimit[$mode];
            }
            $perPageConfigKey = 'catalog/frontend/' . $mode . '_per_page_values';
            $perPageValues = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig($perPageConfigKey);
            $perPageValues = explode(',', $perPageValues);
            $perPageValues = array_combine($perPageValues, $perPageValues);
            if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('catalog/frontend/list_allow_all')) {
                return ($perPageValues + array('all'=>$this->__('All')));
            } else {
                return $perPageValues;
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you tried to do reindex?

Comment: No could this be an indexing issue?

Comment: Are your products "visibility attribute" set to "catalog & search"? And "Status" to enabled? Are all these same products showing up just for regular toolbar settings?

Comment: Yeah all products are showing up on the other settings like show only 12,24 or 72 that all works fine. Except show all

Comment: no luck with reindex?

Comment: No no luck! I´m still looking into it.

Comment: are there any extensions that might affect the catalog? Something that for example reads a parameter from GET and checks if its value is `all` ?

Comment: I created my own product list, its in the same folder and for another product list everything works fine still.

Comment: check the SQL query. After `$_productCollection->count();` do `echo $_productCollection->getSelect()->__toString()` and check if you see something wrong.

Comment: also how do you set the pager? that snippet of code will help someone reproduce it.

Comment: @JulienLachal when I do this then for whatever I have as a Limit on the frontend as the pager I get the Query but if I change it to 'All' then the query does not come up but instead of it a number shows up. So it seems like that when I do 'all' then there is no query

Comment: then what param is sent in the GET request?

Comment: I´ve udpated my question

Comment: doesn't answer my last question unfortunately

Comment: Which GET request do you mean?

Comment: So you have a link or drop down that the user selects to show how many products to show. How does this work? I assume you have something like `count=6` for 6 products so how is the all search done

Comment: I haven´t looked into that because I never changed anything on this function. All I did was creating a new list in app\design\frontend\enterprise\soho\template\catalog\product . There I now have the list.phtml and custom_list.phtml . I also have another copy and for the bacis ones this "All" works fine just not for the custom one.

Comment: @Thomas I think this is custom functionality so tracing how it has been developed should give you have answer.

Comment: Ok thanks though, I thought somehow i can reload the productcollection when I do all, it seems like its not loading it fully then.

Comment: Did you check settings? system_config/edit/section/catalog/key - some strange values there?

Comment: where do i check that?

Comment: Have you modified the collection somewhere in between? Is the issue in custom collection?

Comment: Have checked my repository and can't see any changes there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and spend many hours trying to solve it.
My dev now made a core 'hack' - for those interested;

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php (line 227)

```
    /* FIX: SHOW ALL ITEMS */
    if($this->getLimit() == 'all'){
      $limit = 1000000;
    } else {
      $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    }
```

Beware it's a CORE hack, you will lose the 'fix' when upgrading.
And it's more a bandage then a fix.
But if anyone else have a better solution then please share it.

Comment: You know you can override this by adding your code to the local/Mage rather than hack the core.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking your php settings as loading that many products at one time will be a drain on memory.

I wouldn't necessarily look for things like php memory limits and max load times - but where these are set i would advise a look as it could be getting to outputting 3 but due to other settings it is causing it to fail.